# banner image loading again and again on chrome

Tags: html, nivo-slider

i made this site in html only.this is test site: http://coeindia.in/test/safari/  here slider working perfect but on
Client server it's not working well. 
http://www.safarikidcanada.com/index.htm

i am using nivo silder. i don't have access to client server.  it's
having some problem.specially on chrome , in other browsers working
well

Comment: It's working fine here (last FF version)

Comment: tested in chrome 26.0.1410.64 m - now I see the problem - the images are repeatedly downloaded...

Comment: Tested in chrome, working fine here as well. You do however have an Unexpected identifier on line 7 of script.js.

Comment: @Kisuka its only visible with a slow network connection, or if you check the Network tab in the web developer debugger menu

Comment: @kisuka is that problem happening because of that line 7 of script or something else. as i not using it. any solution for it

Comment: @wikijames Try updating your files. You are using jquery 1.4.3 and nivo slider 2.5. The newest versions are jquery 2.0.0 and nivo slider 3.0

Comment: Otherwise you will need to post an example code which recreates the problem for people to test with. Remove everything from the web page except those elements which create the problem, and then post your html/js files here

Comment: @ozzy ok, i will try to remove that file and also update js. if then also it will create problem , then i will post the code

Comment: @wikijames you should use a CDN for jquery, e.g. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: @Ozzy thank you, yes i will try and have to check on client server, that is main thing..  as  on my server , working well but on this server not working well. if you checked both links